# Using grep and awk to make a new file (tabular separation) from multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

I need to construct a table consisting of unique and shared genes from multiple protein prediction files. I know that I can use grep and awk to look at one particular interest, say unique genes on genome 1, but how can i use the comparison file to extract the number of genes unique to each genome but also numbers of shared genes.

So far I have

```
grep ">" Gen0711.faa | sed -e 's/>//' | while read line; do grep "^$line" Gen0711Gen0994.results | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq | wc -l | tr "\n" "\t"; echo $line; done > Gen0711Gen0994.table
```

But this only gives one area of interest, uniq genes to `Gen0711`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please add example input and desired output. Not mind readers...

Comment: Firstly, the use of grep/sed/sort/uniq/awk/tr/... is way overkill.  Now that you have shown your attempt (always a good sign you tried), please provide a small before and after example of your input so a solution can be sort after?

Comment: How many "protein prediction files" files  what size genomes (in number of predicted proteins per genome)

Comment: I think `wc -l` doesn't help. Also look at `paste`.

Comment: My input files take the genome name and gene ID from each string beginning with > in the .faa files to create the first column of my desired output. The while read line uses the unique genes found in the the .results file and prints this in an adjacent column on the output. I would like to add a command to also determined the shared genes as well as a way to automate this through many .faa  and . results files to create and out put for each corresponding .results file.